# Why am I getting a KeyError for trying to open an excel workbook with xlrd

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlrd, keyerror

I am trying to loop through a folder of excel spreadsheets and open them to extract data and push out to a database. So far I keep getting an error when trying to use xlrd.open_workbook. I am trying to understand what a keyerror is and why I am getting it. Also some ways to get through it is desired.

```
import xlrd as rd

book= 
rd.open_workbook("C:/Users/me/Desktop/PythonSpyderDesktop/Extract/Bob 
Trucking & Warehouse, LLC.xlsm")
```

I was also trying:

```
path = "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\PythonSpyderDesktop\\Extract\\"
book= 
rd.open_workbook(os.path.join(path,'Bob 
Trucking & Warehouse, LLC.xlsm'))
```

This is my error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<ipython-input-99-682ed177f4f5>", line 1, in <module>
book= rd.open_workbook("C:/Users/me/Desktop/PythonSpyderDesktop/Extract/Bob 
Trucking & Warehouse, LLC.xlsm")

File "C:\Python3\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site- 
packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 143, in open_workbook
ragged_rows=ragged_rows,

File "C:\Python3\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site- 
packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 808, in open_workbook_2007_xml
x12book.process_stream(zflo, 'Workbook')

File "C:\Python3\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site- 
packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", 
line 265, in process_stream
meth(self, elem)

File "C:\Python3\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site- 
packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 374, in do_sheet
reltype = self.relid2reltype[rid]

KeyError: ''
```

If I could get some more understanding of a keyerror that would be terrific. I know it has to do with a dictionary object but I have been coding in python for 2 days so I am still grasping the basics. What does the '' key error mean and how can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Just a shot in the dark based on [this github issue](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/issues/276), does the name of the sheet happen to start with a leading 0 ?

Comment: Nope. I also have an if statement skipping the temporary '~' starting excel files found in a folder and only looking at files that end in .xlsx and .xlsm for extraction.

Answer (score 0):

your first code snippet seems to work fine if you sort out the lines that the code are on.

```
import xlrd as rd

book= rd.open_workbook(r'C:/Users/me/Desktop/PythonSpyderDesktop/Extract/Bob Trucking & Warehouse, LLC.xlsm')
```

The program was getting confused and thought that the file name ended at

```
/Extract/Bob
```

and a second started at

```
Trucking & Warehouse, LLC.xlsm")
```

meaning that it was expecting you to use two sets of quotes to signify two different strings. You can also put 'r' in front of paths to files as it means that the interpreter will ignore special symbols such as \$.

Comment: I tried adding that r to make it a raw string but I am still geting KeyError: ''

Comment: The key error is caused by you trying to assign a value to the key 'book', but because the quotation marks around your file path are incorrect, it is failing to assign any value to key.

Comment: How are the quotation marks incorrect? By the way in my actual code the data isnt spaced out on two lines its in one line so it looks like what you have in your first entry. I am still getting the error.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake then. The second error "open_workbook
ragged_rows=ragged_rows," usually indicates some sort of formatting error or corruption in the excel document. I would try re-saving the document if it was downloaded from some sort of business admin software. So try opening the file(s) in Excel first and resaving them, then try executing the script. This will at least rule out file corrupting if the error still occurs.

Comment: So I have discovered that the open_workbook works on certain excel files but not all of them. I am thinking some of them may have something inside the excel document that is conflicting the read operation from going through... The "ragged_rows" error seems to be something of interest...

Comment: try the following: wb = open_workbook(sfile, ragged_rows = True)

Comment: Just gave it a go and still getting the same error. I thought for sure that may have helped..Darn.